# How can i add the columns in top of the grid in pyqt4

Tags: python, pyqt4

Here is my program in that i have a cell of the grid, When i click add rows and columns button, i want to add empty columns and rows for that grid, when i click add columns button, i want to add no of columns in top of the grid not bottom of the grid.But i am getting the bottom of the grid only how can i change the way of adding the columns on top of the grid.Thank you in advance.
This is my code:

```
import sys
from pyface.qt import QtGui, QtCore



class Setting:
    WIDTH = 80
    HEIGHT = 80



class QS(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, x=3, y=4,parent=None):
        super(QS, self).__init__( parent)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y


        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("./img/tick.png").scaled(Setting.WIDTH, Setting.HEIGHT,
            QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)




        for i in range(self.x):
            p = QtCore.QPointF(Setting.WIDTH*i, 0)
            for j in range(self.y):
                item = self.addPixmap(pixmap)
                item.setPos(p)
                p += QtCore.QPointF(0, Setting.HEIGHT)


    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        width = self.x * Setting.WIDTH
        height = self.y * Setting.HEIGHT

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(width, 0))

        for _ in range(self.y+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(0, Setting.HEIGHT)


        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(0, height))

        for _ in range(self.x+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(Setting.WIDTH, 0)

    def Add_columns(self):

            self.y = self.y + 1
            print ("hai")

            self.updateRect()
            print("hello")
            # self.a.drawBackground(painter,rect)
            print 'Columns value of Y is :',self.y



    def Add_rows(self):

            self.x = self.x + 1
            self.updateRect()
            # self.a.drawBackground(painter,rect)
            print 'Row value of  X is :', self.x
    def updateRect(self):
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0,self.x * Setting.WIDTH,self.y* Setting.HEIGHT))


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QS(parent=self)
        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        glayout1 = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
        addRowBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Add")
        addRowBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color:red;border: none;color: white;width: 50px;padding: 15px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;}")
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction('Add a column', scene.Add_columns)
        menu.addAction('Add a row', scene.Add_rows)
        addRowBtn.setMenu(menu)
        glayout1.addWidget(view, 0, 0)
        glayout1.addWidget(addRowBtn, 1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

this is my image:[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

Comment: What have you tried? I see that you have added an empty function, have you tried to implement something?

Comment: yes i tried,i got  my output but the problem is when i click cmd prompt only it is executing

Comment: what is `scrollArea`?

Comment: This is sample code only, actually my code is  above 1000 lines  in that i am using scrollArea. but i  think it is no need here

Comment: Exactly, it is not necessary, but the duty to clean the unnecessary is yours :-), so you must provide a better [mcve] for future opportunities.

Comment: thank you ...can i ask one thing

Comment: i have csv file it consist of 4 values i want to  create a cell of the grid by tacking unique x,y values  from that csv file is it possible? because when i click any one of the cell in grid i want to show the x,y value of the grid, can you please guide me, i want to learn.... is there any method for that .

Comment: Do you know how to read the csv file ?, if you do not know then learn it, there are thousands of solutions in the internet and SO. After loading them the normal thing is to create items, a while ago I answered a question with the same code as your samples where you added images one by one, the same logic you should use to do what you want. there is no direct method, the method is: upload files from python, get every x and y, create an item that shows the value of x and y and finally set it in the scene.

Comment: yes i know by using pandas i done,ok thank you..

Comment: If your goal is just to show the pandas I have created a code to show data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603119/how-to-display-a-pandas-data-frame-with-pyqt5/44605011#44605011

Comment: my goal is to show the unique x,y values in grid, when you click any cell of the grid  it has to show like (x=3,y=0)

Comment: i am very thankful to you because i gained  a lot of things  from your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid the use of global variables, these can be difficult to debug so use must be limited, in this case it is not necessary since it is only necessary to create attributes of the class. On the other hand the simplest solution is to call update or establish a new sceneRect that will call update internally and that the latter will force the repaint.

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui


class Setting:
    WIDTH = 80
    HEIGHT = 80


class QS(QtGui.QGraphicsScene):
    def __init__(self, x=7, y=5, parent=None):
        super(QS, self).__init__(parent)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.updateRect()

    def updateRect(self):
        self.setSceneRect(QtCore.QRectF(0, 0, self.x * Setting.WIDTH, self.y * Setting.HEIGHT))

    def drawBackground(self, painter, rect):
        width = self.x * Setting.WIDTH
        height = self.y * Setting.HEIGHT

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(width, 0))
        for _ in range(self.y+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(0, Setting.HEIGHT)

        l = QtCore.QLineF(QtCore.QPointF(0, 0), QtCore.QPointF(0, height))
        for _ in range(self.x+1):
            painter.drawLine(l)
            l.translate(Setting.WIDTH, 0)

        pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap("p1.png").scaled(Setting.WIDTH, 
            Setting.HEIGHT, 
            QtCore.Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation)

        p = QtCore.QPointF()
        for i in range(self.x):
            p = QtCore.QPointF(Setting.WIDTH*i, 0)
            for j in range(self.y):
                painter.drawPixmap(p, pixmap)
                p += QtCore.QPointF(0, Setting.HEIGHT)

    def Add_columns(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.updateRect()

    def Add_rows(self):
        self.y += 1
        self.updateRect()


class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        scene = QS(parent=self)
        view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(scene)
        widget = QtGui.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)
        glayout1 = QtGui.QGridLayout(widget)
        addRowBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("Add")
        addRowBtn.setStyleSheet("QPushButton {background-color:red;border: none;color: white;width: 50px;padding: 15px;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;font-size: 16px;margin: 4px 2px;}")
        menu = QtGui.QMenu(self)
        menu.addAction('Add a column', scene.Add_columns)
        menu.addAction('Add a row', scene.Add_rows)
        addRowBtn.setMenu(menu)
        glayout1.addWidget(view, 0, 0)
        glayout1.addWidget(addRowBtn, 1, 1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @navyasri Why have you unchecked my answer as correct?

Comment: here my adding columns are added to bottom of the grid,but i want to add top of the grid how can i change the way of adding_columns

Comment: i changed the y positions and main drawBackground setting but still i am getting the my columns are added to bottom of the grid only

Comment: @navyasri Why do you think they are added down or to the right? What is your reference system? And if it is added to the left or above as you see it ?, in the case of my solution I increase in 1 the number of rows, that is: [0, r] -> [0, r + 1] in the for loop, but you should do [0, r] -> [-1, r], then -> [- 2, r] and so on.