# PYQT5 open secondwindow on botton click in the mainwindow, window uses object

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(662, 512)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 160, 113, 20))

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 662, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push botton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "label1:"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

        MainWindow.show()

    def btn_clk(self):

        self.SW = Ui_SecondWindow()
        SecondWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
        self.SW.setupUi(SecondWindow)
        self.SW.show()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self,SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(662, 512)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")


        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar...

        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self,SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "SecondWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Push botton2"))

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

        SecondWindow.show()

    def btn_clk(self):
        return 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I want to open my second window when the push botton is clicked in my mainwindow, but I tried and when I click it, the mainwindow closes. Can anyone help?

For the part `def_btn` in my mainwindow, can anyone check the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(662, 512)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")

        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)          # +++
        self.label.setObjectName("label")                          # +++
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 140, 113, 20))    # +++

        self.itemText = ""                                            # +++
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)       # +++
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")                       # +++
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 140, 100, 20))    # +++        

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 160, 113, 20))

        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 662, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Push botton"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "label1:"))            ###

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)

#        MainWindow.show()

    def btn_clk(self):

        SecondWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow(MainWindow)  # +
        self.SW = Ui_SecondWindow()
        self.SW.setupUi(SecondWindow)
# AttributeError: 'Ui_SecondWindow' object has no attribute 'show'        
#        self.SW.show()
        SecondWindow.show()                               # +

        self.SW.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clkSecondWindow)
        self.SW.tableWidget.itemPressed[QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem].connect(self.cell_Activated)
# +        
    def btn_clkSecondWindow(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.itemText)
# +        
    def cell_Activated(self, item):
        self.itemText = item.text()

class Ui_SecondWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self,SecondWindow):
        SecondWindow.setObjectName("SecondWindow")
        SecondWindow.resize(662, 512)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(SecondWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
# +++
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['Product', 'Description', 'Likes/UnLikes'])

        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.horizontalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)
        SecondWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
# ?       self.menubar...
        self.retranslateUi(SecondWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(SecondWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self,SecondWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        SecondWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("SecondWindow", "SecondWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("SecondWindow", "Push botton2"))

#        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.btn_clk)
#        SecondWindow.show()
#    def btn_clk(self):
#        return 0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much! That works. And I have another question, if I add a textbox in my Mainwindow and add a tableview in my second window, and I take the path to be my textbox text   `path = self.lineEdit.text()`   how can I, when clicking the push botton in mainwindow, give me a table with a dataframe from this path in my second window?                                                                      I use this link for display the pandas dataframe in my pyqt5     [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44603119/how-to-display-a-pandas-data-frame-with-pyqt5)

Comment: @Cindy. Please mark this answer as solved (mark under vote buttons) to show other people that the question is solved and it also give the person who answered some credit. New question should I recommend to start as a new Question. :).