# Displaying pandas dataframe in QML

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, qml, pyqt5

I have 2 pandas `dataframes`, one with `6 rows` and `7 columns` and another one with `21 rows` and `12 columns`, i would like to display them using QML, while googling i got to know about TableView [TableView QML Type](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-tableview.html).  In that example, the data has been entered already in `ListElement` and it is being shown. But in my case the data is from python pandas dataframe, how can i fetch the columns and rows from pandas straight into QML, should i create those columns well before under `listelement`? Any help would be appreciated

**Note**: I have used `QtWidgets` to display dataframe, it was just a drag and drop tableview and use the model created and set them using `tableView.setModel(model)`. But i am kind of clueless here in QML

Comment: i am using pyqt5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a class that inherits from `QAbstractTableModel` as implemented in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605011/6622587) and use the [QTableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.12/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) of QtQuick 2.12 that was released in Qt 5.12 since it supports the `QAbstractTableModel` type model, so you will have to use the latest versions of PyQt5.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtQml
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

class DataFrameModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel):
    DtypeRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000
    ValueRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1001

    def __init__(self, df=pd.DataFrame(), parent=None):
        super(DataFrameModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self._dataframe = df

    def setDataFrame(self, dataframe):
        self.beginResetModel()
        self._dataframe = dataframe.copy()
        self.endResetModel()

    def dataFrame(self):
        return self._dataframe

    dataFrame = QtCore.pyqtProperty(pd.DataFrame, fget=dataFrame, fset=setDataFrame)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int, QtCore.Qt.Orientation, result=str)
    def headerData(self, section: int, orientation: QtCore.Qt.Orientation, role: int = QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
                return self._dataframe.columns[section]
            else:
                return str(self._dataframe.index[section])
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def rowCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return len(self._dataframe.index)

    def columnCount(self, parent=QtCore.QModelIndex()):
        if parent.isValid():
            return 0
        return self._dataframe.columns.size

    def data(self, index, role=QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole):
        if not index.isValid() or not (0 <= index.row() < self.rowCount() \
            and 0 <= index.column() < self.columnCount()):
            return QtCore.QVariant()
        row = self._dataframe.index[index.row()]
        col = self._dataframe.columns[index.column()]
        dt = self._dataframe[col].dtype

        val = self._dataframe.iloc[row][col]
        if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
            return str(val)
        elif role == DataFrameModel.ValueRole:
            return val
        if role == DataFrameModel.DtypeRole:
            return dt
        return QtCore.QVariant()

    def roleNames(self):
        roles = {
            QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole: b'display',
            DataFrameModel.DtypeRole: b'dtype',
            DataFrameModel.ValueRole: b'value'
        }
        return roles

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import os
    import sys

    app = QtGui.QGuiApplication(sys.argv)
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(6, 7)), columns=list('ABCDEFG'))
    print(df)
    model = DataFrameModel(df)
    engine = QtQml.QQmlApplicationEngine()
    engine.rootContext().setContextProperty("table_model", model)
    qml_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "main.qml")
    engine.load(QtCore.QUrl.fromLocalFile(qml_path))
    if not engine.rootObjects():
        sys.exit(-1)
    engine.quit.connect(app.quit)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**main.qml**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.11

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    color: '#222222'

    TableView {
        id: tableView

        columnWidthProvider: function (column) { return 100; }
        rowHeightProvider: function (column) { return 60; }
        anchors.fill: parent
        leftMargin: rowsHeader.implicitWidth
        topMargin: columnsHeader.implicitHeight
        model: table_model
        delegate: Rectangle {
            color: parseFloat(display) > 50 ? 'green' : 'red'
            Text {
                text: display
                anchors.fill: parent
                anchors.margins: 10
                color: 'white'
                font.pixelSize: 15
                verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
            }
        }
        Rectangle { // mask the headers
            z: 3
            color: "#222222"
            y: tableView.contentY
            x: tableView.contentX
            width: tableView.leftMargin
            height: tableView.topMargin
        }

        Row {
            id: columnsHeader
            y: tableView.contentY
            z: 2
            Repeater {
                model: tableView.columns > 0 ? tableView.columns : 1
                Label {
                    width: tableView.columnWidthProvider(modelData)
                    height: 35
                    text: table_model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Horizontal)
                    color: '#aaaaaa'
                    font.pixelSize: 15
                    padding: 10
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                    background: Rectangle { color: "#333333" }
                }
            }
        }
        Column {
            id: rowsHeader
            x: tableView.contentX
            z: 2
            Repeater {
                model: tableView.rows > 0 ? tableView.rows : 1
                Label {
                    width: 40
                    height: tableView.rowHeightProvider(modelData)
                    text: table_model.headerData(modelData, Qt.Vertical)
                    color: '#aaaaaa'
                    font.pixelSize: 15
                    padding: 10
                    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter

                    background: Rectangle { color: "#333333" }
                }
            }
        }

        ScrollIndicator.horizontal: ScrollIndicator { }
        ScrollIndicator.vertical: ScrollIndicator { }
    }
}
```

[image]

I have used:

- Python 3.7.2
- PyQt5 5.12.1
- Qt 5.12.2
- pandas 0.24.1

**Note:** If you want to use the example with PySide2 you only have to change `pyqtProperty` with `Property`, `pyqtSlot` with `Slot` and `PyQt5` to `PySide2`.

Comment: @Techiesoft In the TableView of Qt Quick 2.12  they do not come with headers but implementing them is easy with Column, Row and Repeaters as I did in my answer

Comment: what is that index on the left..is it coming from pandas dataframe?

Comment: if i want to change the cell color based on the numbers , should i write any js function?

Comment: Sorted Dataframes not showing up as expected, added the image in the question, can you please check

Comment: that is not the case, what i wanted is to display the pandas dataframe i got as output as it is.i hope you understand that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190575/discussion-between-techiesoft-and-eyllanesc).